# searching within a list/dictionary error

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have written a web crawler that returns currency exchange values as a nested list and i am trying to write a part of the code that will search through this list for a given name and extract the currency value data associated with it.

my records function looks like

```
[['Argentine Peso', ['9.44195', '0.10591']], ['Australian Dollar', ['1.41824', '0.70510']]
```

and the function is supposed to be able to search for a currency name like "Argentine Peso" and return

```
[9.44195,0.10591]
```

how would i go about that?

```
def findCurrencyValue(records, currency_name):
    l = [[(records)]]
    d = dict(l)
    d[currency_name]
    return(d)
def main():
    url = "https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/jind/exchangerate.html"
    records = fetch(url)
    findCurrencyValue(records, "Argentine Peso")
    print(findCurrencyValue)
    print("currency exchange information is\n", records)
main()
```

but i get the error

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Comment: I replied to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490506/list-dictionary-error-in-my-code/33490714#33490714 you should try it.

Comment: im not allowed to use external programs

Answer (score 4):

You are using the wrong data structure. Convert your nested list to a dictionary then you can easy index based on your currency

**Implementation**

```
data = [['Argentine Peso', ['9.44195', '0.10591']], ['Australian Dollar', ['1.41824', '0.70510']]]
data_dict = dict(data)
```

**Usage**

```
>>> data_dict['Argentine Peso']
['9.44195', '0.10591']
```

**Update**

Referring back to your code, your approach in nesting the data (`record`) is contriving, which is preventing it to convert to a usable dictionary index-able by currency

```
l = [[(records)]]
d = dict(l) 

>>> dict([[(data)]])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#240>", line 1, in <module>
    dict([[(data_dict)]])
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

**Solution**

Change the line

```
findCurrencyValue(records, "Argentine Peso")
```

to

```
records = dict(records)
findCurrencyValue = records["Argentine Peso"]
```

and remove the function `findCurrencyValue`

```
def findCurrencyValue(records, currency_name):
    d = dict(records)
    return(d[currency_name])
def main():
    url = "https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/jind/exchangerate.html"
    records = fetch(url)
    curreny_value = findCurrencyValue(records, "Argentine Peso")
    print(curreny_value )
    print("currency exchange information is\n", records)
main()
```

Comment: is there a way to do it keeping the structure i have?

Comment: If the solution seems difficult to you, then the answer is NO.

Comment: i mean cant i keep the function but still change the records to a dictionary properly?

Comment: @NoahDukehart: Just change the line `l = [[(records)]]` to `l = records`, and you should be good to go

Comment: i keep getting the printed value  "<function findCurrencyValue at 0x0335BDB0>"

Comment: thank you so much i see what you did and after reading some other articles i think i understand why my way didnt work. thank you